# Doctrine Fixture Data load - Value missing from insert

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I've the following entities (School and Circuit) created in my symfony2/doctrine2 project with a many-To-One (A circuit contains one or more schools) bi-directional relationship.
Here is the [Schoool.orm.yml](http://pastebin.com/f7HDbx4E) and [circuit.orm.yml](http://pastebin.com/EdE1g6uR) definition

I'm trying to load the corresponding data fixture for each of this entities as shown  below:

```
 //Circuit Fixture
    public function load(ObjectManager $em) {
            $newCirco = new Circonscription();
            $newCirco->setId(1);
            $newCirco->setLibelle('Circuit1');

            $em->persist($newCirco);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addReference('circo1', $newCirco);
    }


    //School Fixture
     public function load(ObjectManager $em) {
            //Ecoles - Circo 1
            $ecole = new Etablissement();
            $ecole->setRne('0310211L');
            $ecole->setCirconscription($em->merge($this->getReference('circo1')));
            $ecole->setLibelle('FRANCE');
            $ecole->setAdresse('6 AVENUE DE Test');
            $ecole->setTelphone('05xxxxxxxx');
            $ecole->setEmail('xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxe.fr');

            $em->persist($ecole);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addReference('ecole', $ecole);
    }
```

However, i get a `NotNullConstraintViolationException`from Doctrine related to an integrity violation .

```
 An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO etablissement (rne, libe
  lle, adresse, telphone, email, circo_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with pa
  rams ["0310241U", null, null, null, null, null]:
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'libelle' cann
  ot be null
```

Though the value have been defined in the fixture.
What could probably be the source of this error?or Why the insert generated by doctrine doesn't contain the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your school fixture try to change the argument of `setCirconscription()`:

```
 public function load(ObjectManager $em) {

        $ecole = new Etablissement();
        $ecole->setRne('0310211L');
        $ecole->setCirconscription($this->getReference('circo1'));

        /.../

}
```

And do not forget to load `Circuit Fixture` before `School Fixture`

Comment: why does'it work with the `$this->getReference()` and not the Object Manager? Just to understand

Comment: It works because your class extends `AbstractFixture`: `Abstract Fixture class helps to manage references between fixture classes in order to set relations among other fixtures`